# P2P Network. How to determine the main server

Tags: privacy

How to detect if your phone iPhone 6plus is the server/ main computer in a p2p network?

Comment: In a p2p network, by definition, there is no main computer.

Answer (score 1):

In P2P, there is no main servers. Every devices are connected with several others devices:
[image]

Maybe you talk about the trackers when you said main servers. Sometimes there is a tracker which give a list of seeders (uploaders) to the leechers (downloaders), but this is a dedicated which is the tracker.  Others times the can found others peer with the protocol DHT.